# javascript reduce method want to add up values by having a condition statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sum up values by using reduce method, since I am new to JavaScript I need some help with condition statement when adding app all the values, I have a selector method where I select days and then there are movement on each days, I want to add all those movements but not want to include first and last day movements when I calculate sum by using reduce method.

```
export const getTotalMoveCount = createSelector(
  getMachineDailyMoves,
  dailyMoves => dailyMoves.reduce((sum, day) => sum + day.get(MoveTypes.movesTotal), 0)
);
```

Each day has totalmoves, and with this method I want to count total movecounts by adding up all days moves, for example if i select days from 10jan to 16jan, then it will add all the movements from 11jan to 15 jan, I want that there will be some condition statement which ignores first and last day of selection, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use slice: `[1,2,3,4,5].slice(1,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the first and last items using `slice()` and then `reduce()` it:

```js
const result = [5, 10, 2, 3, 4].slice(1, -1)
                .reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => accumulator + currentValue);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just ignore the first and last values of the index then, which is the 3rd parameter of the [`reduce` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

```
export const getTotalMoveCount = createSelector(
  getMachineDailyMoves,
  (dailyMoves) => {
    return dailyMoves.reduce((sum, day, index) => {
      if (index !== 0 && index !== dailyMoves.length - 1) {
        return sum + day.get(MoveTypes.movesTotal);
      }

      return sum;
    }, 0);
  }
);
```

Comment: if (index !== 0 && index !== dailyMoves.length - 1), it ignores the moves from sum when index !==0 but does not ignore when other condition I mean this seems index !== dailyMoves.length - 1  not working,

Comment: OP asked to ignore the first and last items of the array in the count. The above code does that.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not getting into your app details.
This is the way to ignore first & last values:

```
const x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  if (currentIndex == 0 || currentIndex == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].length-1)
    return accumulator
  return accumulator + currentValue;
});

alert(x) // console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and clear code:

```js
const sum = (arr) => {
    arr.shift();
    arr.pop();
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sum([5, 10, 2, 3, 4]));
```

For your case:

```
export const getTotalMoveCount = createSelector(
    getMachineDailyMoves,
    (dailyMoves) => {
        dailyMoves.shift();
        dailyMoves.pop();
        return dailyMoves.reduce((sum, day) => sum + day.get(MoveTypes.movesTotal), 0)
    }
);
```